# How to run python3 from cmd.exe

Tags: python, path, windows-8.1

I see the following text when I type `python` in my Windows 8.1 console (cmd.exe)

> Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
>   D64)] on win32

I want to run **python3.6** version when I type `python`.

**What I tried**

1) Entered python3 and python3.6, but I didn't work

2) downloaded python3 and added it to the PATH variable

> C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin; c:\Go\bin; ;%PyCharm%; C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Education\5\dev\chrome;;C:\Program Files\gretl;C:\chromedriver;C:\chromium-automation;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6;

Comment: What do you get when you type `python3` or `python3.6`? Not using windows but I have many python versions installed and usually use aliases to use the version I need. Also, I noticed this *C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38* so you must be installing `3.8` and not `3.6`

Comment: @mad_ these commands did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python launcher with the `py -3` or `py -3.6` command to explicitly invoke python3.

The path you posted is not your complete path. It is just the user path. The system path takes precedence over it and has python2 in it.
You can uninstall python2 to fix this. Or if you want to keep it, uninstall and reinstall python 3.6 remembering to choose the `Add Python to PATH` checkbox in the installer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove python 2 installation directory from PATH before adding python 3 directory to PATH.

Comment: My python2 path -- C:\Python27
Did not find this in my PATH variable, could you please elaborate your answer?